# How to remove all duplicates from list

Tags: java, list, minecraft, bukkit

Currently I am attempting to remove ALL duplicates from a list. However, from what I gather, this will only remove them if the total amount is divisible by 2. How can I edit it so it will get all copies, if it were 3 or 5, or more?

```
    if(check.size() < recipes.size()) { //check is a set, checking for copies.
        logger.warning("We found a copy of names, please change them! We will be disabling those recipes to disable errors.");
        for(int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < recipes.size(); j++) {
                if(recipes.get(i) == recipes.get(j) && i != j) {
                    logger.warning("We found copies of " + recipes.get(i));
                    recipes.remove(i);
                    recipes.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently it will only remove 2 values from the list.

Also, if there are copies, I don't want 1 copy remaining, I wish to remove them all as to avoid errors later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple options, one of which would be to use an implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as it is inherently collection that compels to uniqueness. Another one of the options would be to create a new list and use lambdas to get distinct elements, for example let's say you want to copy only unique/distinct elements from "recipes" list to new list "recipesUnique", you could do this:

```
ArrayList<T> recipesUnique = new ArrayList<>();
recipes.stream().distinct().forEach(recipesUnique::add);
```

There are many more possible solutions, if you ask me, lambdas are the simplest one if you are obliged to use List, otherwise just use `Set`.

Comment: I am still rather new to Java. I don't really understand Lambdas all that much so I'll stick to using the set one, however I'll keep this post in mind when I get to lambdas. Thanks for the assistance.